# Multiple language (but same value) count in Laravel

Tags: database, laravel, mysqli, database-design, multilingual

My Goal: To find out which University has the larger amount of user (DISTINCT and COUNT in MySQLi).

I've been developing a survey website for Portugal, England and France.

In the survey some questions answer has predefined answer options.

For example: Gender, Living Country, Graduation Level (undergraduate, graduate, PhD, BBA etc)

But I also have questions where users need to write down the answers.

For example, University Name (where the user studied).

Two users filled the form as follow:

In this case the text "**University of Glasgow**" in **English** and the text "**Universidade of Glasgow**" in **Portuguese** is difference but it's the same institute.

So, these two institute has one user but the truth is this (as both are originally same University) University has two users.

My Question: How can I get the expected result?

I was planning to use Google translate but I it won't be accurate.

I also thought about to have all the University name in 3 languages but there are more than thousands of University, so it may not be efficient.

The structre I thought for table is,

survey_table

> id, que_en, que_fr, que_pt, university_name

statistics_table

> id, university_name, count

Answer (score 0):

You could use localization for the university name. Check the docs here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/localization

Make your users choose from a drop down list based on their locale (language)

Comment: That won't help. As the list is too long and even if I do it by Ajax that won't be efficient. it'll use unnecessary server resources

Comment: Do you have a list of universities for required languages?